# Download Manager with PHP and JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, download

I have an issue. This is a simple file downloader. I want 2 more things and I don't know how to set it up.

1. Make multi selection possible for the images.
2. Download selected images at once using the button in "li .multiselect".

I don't know how to set it up.

Can someone help please?

Thanks.

Here is the code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Download-Manager</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php

    // Glob function
    $images = glob('./assets/Bilder/*');
    $stock = glob('./assets/Lagerbestand/*');
    $texts = glob('./assets/Web-Texte/*');

    ?>
    <div class="wrapper download">
      <h1>Download Manager</h1>
      <h2>Bilder</h2>
      <ul class="download-list images">
        <?php
          foreach ($images as $image) {
            //$image_info = getimagesize($image);
            list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($image);
            //print_r($image_info);
            $size = filesize($image);
            $round = round($size / 1024 / 1024, 2);

            echo '<li class="list-item">';
            echo '<input class="checkbox" name="downloadfile[]" type="checkbox" />';
            echo '<div class="thumb"><img src="'. $image .'" alt="" /></div>';
            echo '<div class="content">';
            echo '<p class="filename"><span class="title">Dateiname</span>' . str_replace('./assets/Bilder/', '', $image) . '</p>';
            echo '<p class="width-height"><span class="title">Abmessungen:</span> ' . $width . ' x ' . $height . ' Px</p>';
            echo '<p class="size"><span class="title">Größe:</span> ' . $round . ' MBytes</p>';
            echo '<a class="btn link" href="'. $image .'" download="'. $image .'">Download <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M20 15v4c0 0.276-0.111 0.525-0.293 0.707s-0.431 0.293-0.707 0.293h-14c-0.276 0-0.525-0.111-0.707-0.293s-0.293-0.431-0.293-0.707v-4c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1s-1 0.448-1 1v4c0 0.828 0.337 1.58 0.879 2.121s1.293 0.879 2.121 0.879h14c0.828 0 1.58-0.337 2.121-0.879s0.879-1.293 0.879-2.121v-4c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1s-1 0.448-1 1zM13 12.586v-9.586c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1s-1 0.448-1 1v9.586l-3.293-3.293c-0.391-0.391-1.024-0.391-1.414 0s-0.391 1.024 0 1.414l5 5c0.092 0.092 0.202 0.166 0.324 0.217s0.253 0.076 0.383 0.076c0.256 0 0.512-0.098 0.707-0.293l5-5c0.391-0.391 0.391-1.024 0-1.414s-1.024-0.391-1.414 0z"></path>
            </svg></a>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</li>';
          }
        ?>
        <li class="multiselect"><a class="btn link" href="download" download="download">Download Multi Images<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M20 15v4c0 0.276-0.111 0.525-0.293 0.707s-0.431 0.293-0.707 0.293h-14c-0.276 0-0.525-0.111-0.707-0.293s-0.293-0.431-0.293-0.707v-4c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1s-1 0.448-1 1v4c0 0.828 0.337 1.58 0.879 2.121s1.293 0.879 2.121 0.879h14c0.828 0 1.58-0.337 2.121-0.879s0.879-1.293 0.879-2.121v-4c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1s-1 0.448-1 1zM13 12.586v-9.586c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1s-1 0.448-1 1v9.586l-3.293-3.293c-0.391-0.391-1.024-0.391-1.414 0s-0.391 1.024 0 1.414l5 5c0.092 0.092 0.202 0.166 0.324 0.217s0.253 0.076 0.383 0.076c0.256 0 0.512-0.098 0.707-0.293l5-5c0.391-0.391 0.391-1.024 0-1.414s-1.024-0.391-1.414 0z"></path>
        </svg></a></li>
      </ul>
      <h2>Lagerbestand</h2>
      <ul class="download-list stock">
        <?php
          foreach ($stock as $s) {
            echo '<li class="list-item">';
            echo '<div class="content">';
            echo '<p class="filename"><span class="title">Dateiname</span>' . str_replace('./assets/Lagerbestand/', '', $s) . '</p>';
            echo '<a class="btn link" href="'. $s .'" download="'. $s .'">Download <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M20 15v4c0 0.276-0.111 0.525-0.293 0.707s-0.431 0.293-0.707 0.293h-14c-0.276 0-0.525-0.111-0.707-0.293s-0.293-0.431-0.293-0.707v-4c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1s-1 0.448-1 1v4c0 0.828 0.337 1.58 0.879 2.121s1.293 0.879 2.121 0.879h14c0.828 0 1.58-0.337 2.121-0.879s0.879-1.293 0.879-2.121v-4c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1s-1 0.448-1 1zM13 12.586v-9.586c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1s-1 0.448-1 1v9.586l-3.293-3.293c-0.391-0.391-1.024-0.391-1.414 0s-0.391 1.024 0 1.414l5 5c0.092 0.092 0.202 0.166 0.324 0.217s0.253 0.076 0.383 0.076c0.256 0 0.512-0.098 0.707-0.293l5-5c0.391-0.391 0.391-1.024 0-1.414s-1.024-0.391-1.414 0z"></path>
            </svg></a>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</li>';
          }
        ?>
      </ul>
      <h2>Web Texte</h2>
      <ul class="download-list texts">
        <?php
          foreach ($texts as $text) {
            echo '<li class="list-item">';
            echo '<div class="content">';
            echo '<p class="filename"><span class="title">Dateiname</span>' . str_replace('./assets/Web-Texte/', '', $text) . '</p>';
            echo '<a class="btn link" href="'. $text .'" download="'. $text .'">Download <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M20 15v4c0 0.276-0.111 0.525-0.293 0.707s-0.431 0.293-0.707 0.293h-14c-0.276 0-0.525-0.111-0.707-0.293s-0.293-0.431-0.293-0.707v-4c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1s-1 0.448-1 1v4c0 0.828 0.337 1.58 0.879 2.121s1.293 0.879 2.121 0.879h14c0.828 0 1.58-0.337 2.121-0.879s0.879-1.293 0.879-2.121v-4c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1s-1 0.448-1 1zM13 12.586v-9.586c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1s-1 0.448-1 1v9.586l-3.293-3.293c-0.391-0.391-1.024-0.391-1.414 0s-0.391 1.024 0 1.414l5 5c0.092 0.092 0.202 0.166 0.324 0.217s0.253 0.076 0.383 0.076c0.256 0 0.512-0.098 0.707-0.293l5-5c0.391-0.391 0.391-1.024 0-1.414s-1.024-0.391-1.414 0z"></path>
            </svg></a>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</li>';
          }
        ?>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

      // check checkbox
      $('.images .list-item').click(function(){
        if( $(this).find('.checkbox').prop('checked')){
          $(this).find('.checkbox').removeAttr('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
          $(this).find('.checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
      });

      // update checkbox
      $('.images .list-item').find('.checkbox').change(function() {
          alert ("The element with id " + this.id + " changed.");
      });

    });


    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're much more likely to get an answer on here if you start and try yourself.  Once you have a discrete problem you can demonstrate, ask again.

Comment: Hi @Quasipickle, thank you. I tried a lot and I have no idea how to make it work. That's why I tried to ask the community :)

Comment: What exactly did you try? What went wrong? Show your best attempt please, then we can suggest ways to fix / improve it. That's how it works here - you show some code and we fix a specific issue with it...we don't just write whole features for people from nothing. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @ADyson thank for your feedback. As you can see in the JS part I tried to update the checkbox with a very simple jquery, but this doesn’t work for example. :) view // update checkbox